# How To Add Xml Data to Accsess Data Base Error

Tags: c#, xml, ms-access

i have written a program that processes XML and imports that into an Accsess table however it produces errors. I have an sql injection type statment I think thats not quite right some how.

```
The Database(Accsess) has this
Index    Field 1 Autonumber primary key
Property Field 2 ShortText
PValue   Field 3 ShortText
PDefault Field 4 ShortText
Ptype    Field 5 ShortText
```

My Code Produces this error 
    `Error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): Parameter ?_1 has no default value.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Beta3.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users`

```
An this is the code that produces it.

String files;
        files = "c:\\temp\\launch.xml";
        SetCon.Text = SetCon.Text + "Processing Lauch Working \n";
        String item1, item2, item3, item4;
        XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(files);

        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            item1 = reader1.GetAttribute("name");
            item2 = reader1.GetAttribute("amount");
            item3 = reader1.GetAttribute("default");
            item4 = reader1.GetAttribute("group");
            try
            {
                SetCon.Text = SetCon.Text + "Adding Records \n";
                string ConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\Set.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
                string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Launch([Property], [PValue], [PDefault],[PType]) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
                using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, Conn))
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Property", item1);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PValue", item2);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PDefault", item3);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PType", item4);

                        Conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Conn.Close();
                    }

                }
```

I think its the autonumber causing the errors like but Iam not experienced enough to know about it. MAybe some on here can spot what Iam doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try use `@` instead of `?` ?

Try this:

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Launch([Property], [PValue], [PDefault],[PType]) VALUES('@Property','@PValue','@PDefault','@PType')";
                using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, Conn))
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property", item1);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PValue", item2);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PDefault", item3);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PType", item4);

                        Conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Conn.Close();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): Parameter @ has no default value.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.

Comment: This example workes the edited example but as I have discovered If I add the code (copy paste) then it only filles the columes/records with the text item1, item2 .. .. . . It does not put in the actual varibles values. @ ohadinho Plz check your coded exable table for the sams